# Qual è il senso di "girare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Dall'albero, egli stava delle mezz'ore fermo a guardare i loro lavori e faceva domande sugli ingrassi e le semine, cosa che camminando sulla terra non gli era mai venuto di fare, trattenuto da quella ritrosia che non gli faceva mai rivolgere parola ai villici ed ai servi. A volte, indicava se il solco che stavano zappando veniva diritto o storto, o se nel campo del vicino erano già maturi i pomodori; a volte s'offriva di far loro piccole commissioni come andare a dire alla moglie d'un falciatore che gli desse una cote, o ad avvertire che **girassero** l'acqua in un orto.

Ho cercato il verbo "girare" in parecchi dizionari ma, tra le diverse accezioni che appaiono,  non riesco a capire a quale corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel passaggio precedente . Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Trovi “C’è da girare l'acqua nei fagioli” in “Ultimo viene il corvo” sempre di Calvino e il senso è lo stesso: irrigare.

Answer (score 2):

Girare l'acqua all'orto significa irrigare.

In passato, specie nelle grandi proprietà terriere, erano presenti canali di irrigazione che si diramavano da quello principale.

In questo caso girare ha il significato di irrigare distribuendo l'acqua ai vari campi tramite l'utilizzo di chiuse che venivano aperte o chiuse a seconda delle necessità.

Comment: sì, credo che sia proprio nel senso di _far circolare_ l'acqua nell'orto

Comment: Non credo che canali di irrigazione e chiuse abbiano veramente attinenza con un *orto*.

Comment: Beh, dipende quanto è grande l'orto... Il senso è comunque irrigare distribuendo l'acqua

Answer (score 0):

Girare è un verbo che, come molti, può avere molti significati; in questo specifico caso, si intende far circolare l'acqua nei vari canali di irrigazione. Questo verbo è anche usato in casi come "far girare il motore" che è più o meno simile (si intende di far partire e far funzionare il motore), oltre al suo significato classico.